# Live traffic conditions on google map in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps

How can I add current traffic conditions in ios app using google maps sdk or api as shown in below image.
There is javascript api but I didn't find any solution for iOS app.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add a line of code to enable or disable live traffic in iOS SDK

```
_googleMapsView.trafficEnabled = YES;
_googleMapsView.trafficEnabled = NO;
```

Where `_googleMapsView` is object for `GMSMapView`.