# show traffic on google maps between two markers iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

i am placing a marker and drawing route between my location and the marker placed what i want is to show only the traffic only on the specified route i already know that the syntax `self.map.trafficEnabled = YES;` will show the traffic on the whole map after searching on google i could not find any solution fit my situation

**Things that i found** [Traffic condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406066/live-traffic-conditions-on-google-map-in-ios-app)